# Help on Gossip-Intensive Collator/Substrate Nodes!

Tags: gossip

**Context:** We're running gossip intensive apps and if the workloads get too large, we see all communication drop which breaks down our protocols.

**Question:** Where can I learn learn more about design decisions and constraints on how Substrate nodes will drop each other when being "spammed" to (i.e. when nodes create too many transaction submissions)?

Comment: Please provide more details on what you are doing and what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this will answer 100% your question, but in the [The Polkadot Parachain Host Implementers' Guide](https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot/book/index.html), there are some references on how [Spam is being handled in the dispute mechanism](https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot/book/node/disputes/dispute-coordinator.html?highlight=spam#spam-considerations-1) that might be worth checking out.